# Search string from end of matched word up to X

Tags: regex

The word "name" is dynamic, and I need to find out what it is any given moment through some regex.

```
https://trainingname.website.com/register
```

I got as far as matching https://trainingname but can't isolate name on its own.

This is JavaScript - should have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in JavaScript it will be

```
var result = "https://traininghelloname.website.com/register".match("^https://training([^.]+)\.")[1]
```

So `result` will have the dynamic part. i.e. `helloname` in this case